# Bootstrap 5 navbar won't expand

Tags: html, navbar, bootstrap-5

My I bootstrap 5 navbar only goes as wide as the contents. I would like it to expand the length of the container.  It doesn't change when I change the *navbar-expand-??* setting.
[image]

```
    <div class="container p-3 my-3 bg-primary text-white">

  <h1>Pets to Go <span class="material-icons">pets</span></h1>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="our_pets.html">Our Pets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="current_pets.html">Current Pets</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </nav> <!-- close navbar -->
  
  </div>  <!-- Close main container -->
```

Any idea what is limiting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navbar doesn't "grow" by default. Use `flex-grow-1` if you want it to grow to the width of container-fluid...

```
<div class="container p-3 my-3 bg-primary text-white">
    <h1>Pets to Go <span class="material-icons">pets</span></h1>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Links -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav bg-white flex-grow-1">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="our_pets.html">Our Pets</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="current_pets.html">Current Pets</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav> <!-- close navbar -->
</div> <!-- Close main container -->
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/L4LUmylaj4)

Answer (score 1):

it looks like to me the problem is p-3 and my-3 class in your container div

```
<div class="container p-3 my-3 bg-primary text-white">
```

try to replace it with this

```
<div class="container bg-primary text-white">
```

and assign p-3 and my-3 only in particular div where you needed it inside your container

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it didn't fix it.

Comment: have you try to remove div with container-fluid class?,  it could be other reason to that limiting the expand of your nav